# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Slow when press Super key or clicking Show Applications

Tags: gnome, 18.04, performance

I used to have Deepin installed but recently I’ve been trying out Ubuntu 18.04.1 (GNOME 3.28.2) but it doesn’t feel as fluid compared to Deepin.

When I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key or <kbd>Super</kbd> key, it freezes for a small moment. Same when I click the <kbd>Show Applications</kbd> button. I don't know if this is normal. Is there a fix?

My laptop:

```
6gb Ram
a8 4500m
128gb SSD
```

I know my laptop is not the best but it works perfectly with Deepin, Manjaro Deepin, Windows, Elementary etc. I don't know maybe it’s just GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it slower by disabling animation in `Gnome Tweaks`.

Or if you have `Dash to Dock` installed you can go to:

`Dash to Dock Settings > Launchers > Animate Show Applications > Disable`.